# The Androidphone cannot Detected our NFC tag

Tags: android, nfc

I have two kinds of tags, one is NXP and the other is mine. The two tags write the same nDef data, which can be correctly detected by the IOS mobile phone and realize the NFC function of the tag. However, the Android mobile phone can only detect the nDef data on the NXP tag, but cannot detect the nDef data on my tag. Why? My tag has also passed NFC Forum Certification.

Comment: What Tag type has it been certified as (Type1, Type2, Type3, etc?)

Comment: thank you at first ,we have type2,type5 ,also passed NFC Forum Certification,also can detect by IOS,but can't by andriod

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the only thing I can think of is the [Ndef Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef) say

> It is mandatory for all Android devices with NFC to correctly enumerate Ndef on NFC Forum Tag Types 1-4, and implement all NDEF operations as defined in this class.
>
> Some vendors have their own well defined specifications for storing NDEF data on tags that do not fall into the above categories.
>
> For guaranteed compatibility across all Android devices with NFC, it is recommended to use NFC Forum Types 1-4 in new deployments of NFC tags with NDEF payload.

So type 5 does not have guaranteed support as Android has a number of different NFC hardware suppliers.

If you also look at the [Android Source for NDEF](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android10-release/core/java/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.java#125) it seems that possibly it has some extra support of NXP iCode Sli Ndef support which seem to be Type5 and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277787/2373819 seems to suggest similar experience to you.

Comment: However, the tag of NXP type 5 can be correctly recognized by Android, and the nDef data is the same as the data in our chip,Does the bottom layer of Android have such an interface to obtain the characteristics of the current tag and correctly identify the factory and type when identifying the tag?

Comment: It looks like there is specific support for some NXP Type 5 Tags, added some more detail. Unfortunately I've not been able to get hold of the Type 5 spec document (only read the 1-4 specs)

Comment: I still insist on finding a solution to the problem

Comment: now ,I have test another chip based on the ISO15693, and It can be recongnized by andrord. and the chip also  certified by NFC Forum ,I dont't know Why ,if we will registed the chip's information to andriod? if there is a way to do it ?

Comment: This is something you need to take up with Google I think, the Docs and source suggest that Type 5 support is very lacking in Android, unless your chip can pretend to be exactly a NXP chip it seems you are out of luck.